# Flutter GetSystemMetricsForDpi not located

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-desktop

We build a windows desktop application using flutter desktop and want to distribute it. But after distributing exe file, we got error

**The procedure entry point GetSystemMetricsForDpi could not be located in the dynamic link library USER32.dll**

This error only show in windows 7 and application works properly on windows 10. Please help us to solve this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That function is only available in Windows 10, so there's no way to make your application run on Windows 7 as-is. However, than function isn't used in a stock Flutter application, so either:

- you added it to your Runner code, in which case the solution is not to do that, and to do whatever you are trying to do in a Windows 7-compatible way, or
- you are using a plugin that calls it, in which case you need to either:

  - stop using that plugin, or
  - ask the plugin's developer to support Windows 7.

Comment: I am just trying to add for function in core desktop project code but unable to do that. It their any hack to do that?

Comment: A hack to do what? If you unconditionally link functions from the Windows 10 SDK your app will need Windows 10 to run. That's how the Windows SDK works. I suggest posting a new question where you explain what *functionality* you want to implement using Win32 in a Windows 7-compatible way, rather than asking how to use a Windows 10 API on Windows 7.